# How to search DuckDuckGo with the command-line (tcsh)?

Tags: shell, tcsh

There is a simple function I use a lot to look up things on the web

In Fish

```
function ddg
    set URL "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$(echo "$argv" | tr " " "+")"
    python3 -m webbrowser -t "$URL"
end
```

In ZSH

```
ddg() {
    URL="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$(echo "$*" | tr " " "+")"
    python3 -m webbrowser -t "$URL"
}
```

However I am now required to use tcsh and I don't know how to translate it.

It should be pretty easy but I don't know if I need `eval`, how to access the arguments, etc.

I tried `alias ddg "python3 -m webbrowser -t \"https://duckduckgo.com/?q$(echo '\!*' | tr ' ' '+')\""` but I get the following error

> `Illegal variable name.`

Comment: a tcsh alias can't do what you want. But honestly: you're calling python anyway. Why not simply go for a two line python script that does the same as your shell scripts and just put it in the path (or add an alias to start it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcsh doesn't have functions.

You can kind of work around in a lot of cases where you can e.g. just write a separate tcsh script and pass the argument you want to meddle with to that.

But in all honesty, you're already using a script interpreter, python, which is available on all your machines. So just write a simple Python script!; also, note that you should URL-escape the things you pass as URL parameters; you're not doing that here at all :)

furthermore, your function simply converts all spaces to pluses – that's not what you want; if you type in `ddg cat "toy company"`, you really don't want the space between toy and company to be converted to plus. Also, your shell function doesn't quote argument strings containing spaces, so effectively you've been searching for `cat+toy+company`, where you meant to search for `cat+"toy company"`. Makes a difference! Let's fix that:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Save this file somewhere in your $PATH, or make an `alias` that calls it explicitly
# `chmod 755 filename` will make this file executable

import webbrowser
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlencode

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  """
  no arguments given, just open the DDG homepage
  """
  webbrowser.open("https://duckduckgo.com")
  sys.exit(0)

# enclose arguments that you specifically passed as single argument
# containing space characters with quotation marks
quoted = (f'"{value}"' if " " in value else value for value in sys.argv[1:])
argument = "+".join(quoted)
url = urlencode(f"https://duckduckgo.com/?q{argument}")
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: I guess that's indeed the right way to do it